# Why is $|H \cdot gP|=1$?

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, group-actions, sylow-theory

In the  begining of the Second Sylow Theorem
proof my teacher did the following:

> Let $G$ be finite a group, $P$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ and $H$ any $p$-subgroup. Consider the following group action: $$H\times G/P \to G/P$$ $$(h,xP) \mapsto hxP$$
> Let $\mathcal{O}_1, \mathcal{O}_2, ... \mathcal{O}_k$ be all the orbits.
> Because $p\nmid\ \# G/P$ and $\# G/P = \sum_{i = 1}^k |\mathcal{O}_i|$, we conclude that $\exists i \in \{1,...,k\}$ such that $p \nmid \ \# \mathcal{O}_i$. Let's fix that value for $i$.
>
> Let $g \in G$ such that $\mathcal{O}_i = H\cdot gP$. Because of the Orbit-stabilizer theorem we have that: $$|H |= |H_{gP}| \cdot |H \cdot gP|$$
> And because $H$ is a $p$-group we conclude that $|H \cdot gP|=1$.

I don't get how we can conclude that $|H \cdot gP|=1$ just by knowing that $H$ is a $p$-group and $|H |= |H_{gP}| \cdot |H \cdot gP|$. Why is this true?

Comment: What was your teacher trying to prove here?

Comment: Second Sylow Theorem @Shaun

Comment: Please include that in an [edit].

Comment: I'll do that rn @Shaun

Comment: Done. But Why is that relevant? @Shaun

Comment: Thank you. You never know how helpful these details can be to other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: your equation is of the form

(power of $p$) = (power of $p$) x (coprime to $p$)

Comment: sorry. I don't understand how that might help :/

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães Consider the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm till not being able to see how that's helpful

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães If the orbit size was not $1$, you'd get a contradiction, because the factorization on the left only uses the prime number $p$, but the right side shows there are prime factors other than $p$. They should teach the fundamental theorem of arithmetic well before you take a group theory class...

Comment: But what's stoping the factorization to look like: $|H| = p^2$, $|H_{gP}| = p$ and $|H \cdot gP| = p$ for example?

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães You said $p$ does not divide the size of the orbit. So the orbit size can't be $p$.